# Rails_admin disable export to XML and JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

My app is Rails 4.1.14 with rails_admin 0.8.1.  My users do not need to export data to JSON or XML.  Is there a better way to disable it other than saving my own copy of export.html.haml to app/views/rails_admin/... and removing the links?

Probably not but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. But feel free to submit a pull request.

You can also use the *deface* gem (https://github.com/spree/deface) which allow to modify a view without a complete override.

Comment: Thanks for the deface suggestion.  I am looking into it.